# How can I prove this $x \neq 1$ $\rightarrow$ $\frac{y + 1} {y - 2} = x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Why this solution is not a proof or is incorrect, and how can I solve it?

$\frac{y + 1} {y - 2} = x$, where $y \neq 2$

So we have:

$y + 1$ = $x(y - 2)$

$y + 1 = xy - 2x$

$y - xy = -1 - 2x$

$y(1 - x) =  -1 - 2x$

$y = \frac{-1 - 2x}{1 - x}$

We have find a $y$, which has to be different from 2.

Comment: It looks like you solved it just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to show that for $x \neq 1$, there exists some $y \neq 2$ such that $\frac{y+1}{y-2} = x$, and your computation seems correct. You have a (unique) candidate $y = \frac{-1-2x}{1-x} = \frac{2x+1}{x-1}$. You only need to see that $y \neq 2$. So try to solve for $\frac{2x+1}{x-1} = 2$, and see that this cannot happen for $x \neq 1$.